# find element quickly in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, swift, search, optimization

I have an array of strings that are sorted. Is there a fast way of finding and elements in this array?

I would like to optimise the below function. It's taking too long. The passed array isn't long (only about 15-20 elements) but it is called a lot (about 1000 times.) Currently I just do a `.filter { }` But I think this may be a bottleneck since it goes through the full array 1000 times as opposed to breaking out when finding the first such calendar.

Is there a built-in search that is optimized (i.e., uses a different approach for very small Arrays then midsized or larger ones) similar to the built-in sorting function?

Basically, I'm looking for the counterpart for the built-in sort/sorted functions. It would make a lot of sense to have something like this because you sort arrays often to then find a specific element in them.

```
func startsWithACalendarName(text: String, calendars: [EKCalendar], stripKeywords: Bool = false) -> (newReminderText: String, foundCalendar: EKCalendar?) {
    // make array of words from text
    let words = text.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    // BOTTLENECK? Check if I have a calendar that is equal to first word of text
    let found = calendars.filter { $0.title.lowercaseString == words.head?.lowercaseString }
    return (stripKeywords ? (words.tail?.joinWithSeparator(" "))! : text, found.first)
}
```

Comment: How is the question title related to the question body?

Comment: Sorry, corrected it.

Comment: If it's already sorted you could use a binary search.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli do you have a binary search that is optimized (i.e., uses a different approach for very small Arrays then midsized or larger ones) similar to the built-in sorting function?

Comment: As it goes, it probably won't matter much: https://schani.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/linear-vs-binary-search/

Comment: Are you calling this method with the same set of calendars every time? If so, you could build a map so that lookup time would be O(1).

Comment: @EvanTrimboli that's true. But how would that work? EKCalendar objects have a title property. I would like to search them for a string which is their title. What kind of map would I need that associates these objects with a string?

Comment: I haven't touched Swift before. You probably want to use a set: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this using 'indexOf' instead of 'filter':

```
func startsWithACalendarName(text: String, calendars: [EKCalendar], stripKeywords: Bool = false) -> (newReminderText: String, foundCalendar: EKCalendar?) {
    let words = text.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    var found: EKCalendar?
    if let index = calendars.indexOf ({ $0.title.lowercaseString == words.head?.lowercaseString }) {
        found = calendars[index]
    }
    return (stripKeywords ? (words.tail?.joinWithSeparator(" "))! : text, found) 
}
```

Comment: But, does this take into consideration that the array is already sorted? Because searching a sorted array is considerably faster than finding the index in a non-sorted array.

Comment: It should be better than using `filter`. At this point i would have make a small test measuring the run time for both and see if it's good enough.